# Transfer data between sheets and filter out duplicates in excel

Tags: excel

```
Sheet1= master field that I am trying to copy the content from the other sheets
Sheet2= Distributor1 Column A has UPC Column B Price Column C Shipping Price
Sheet3= Distributor2 Column A has UPC Column B Price Column C Shipping Price
```

In Sheet 1 I would like to paste/copy ALL UPC between sheet 2 and sheet 3. If there is a duplicate (comparing UPC) I would like the lesser of the two transferred over (less of the two column B price not worried about shipping).

I have been trying this all day and cannot get it. Tried copying all UPC to Sheet 1 from both sheets marked the duplicates i just can't get it to work so I don't have duplicated products. Any ideas what would be the easier way and a possible solution?

Comment: If you don't care about the shipping price, you could copy `Distributor2` and paste below `Distributor1` data.  Then `Insert/Pivot Table` and drag `UPC` to the `Rows` area; `Price` to the `Value` area; then edit the `Price` data so it shows `Min` instead of `Sum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this code a shot.  It should do what you need.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicateUPCsAndKeepLowestPrice()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Sht1 As Integer
    Dim Sht2 As Integer
    Dim Sht3 As Integer

    Sht2 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A"))
    Sht3 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A:A"))

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:C").ClearContents
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & Sht2 + Sht3).NumberFormat = "@"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C" & Sht2).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:C" & Sht2).Value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sht2 + 1 & ":C" & (Sht3 + Sht2 - 1)).Value = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:C" & Sht3).Value

    Sheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Sheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A:A"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    Sheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B:B"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A:C")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:C").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlYes

    Sht1 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"))
    For i = 1 To Sht1
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & (i + 1)).Value Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).ClearContents
        End If
    Next i

    Sheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Sheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A:A"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    Sheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B:B"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A:C")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```